# How to make the inside of a cube accessible

Tags: 3d, gui, simulations, turn-based-strategy

I have a cube, it is made up of smaller cubes each making the big cube 8x8x8. The cube is the map. The player of the game needs to be able to appraise the entire map and understand it without having to zoom through the inside of the cube since he may need to see opposite ends and interior at the same time.

How can I make this cube easy for the player to access? 
Requirements:

- Player must be able to see any 2 cubes at the same time, including the interior.
- Player must be able to understand depth of cube
- Player must be able to click on interior cubes.
- Player must be able to differentiate between allied/enemy soldier, and soldier class.

if it helps at all, imagine if the rubiks cube had more cube inside it, obviously in the real world, we have no way to control them, but in a game, how would i allow someone to see and manipulate several at one time. Note: not a realtime game.

Comment: You could try spreading the cubes out so there's space between them. Make a giant 3D grid of the cubes that the player can rotate around, with further ones being smaller to give depth. Since they're all spread out and rotatable, you can see any two cubes at a time and still click the interior ones. Differentiating between unit classes seems like a different question though.

Comment: Yes, i came across this solution a while ago and it works great! put that down as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try spreading the cubes out so there's space between them. Make a giant 3D grid of the cubes that the player can rotate around, with further ones being smaller to give depth. Since they're all spread out and rotatable, you can see any two cubes at a time and still click the interior ones. Differentiating between unit classes seems like a different question though.